# String Formating and Passing

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, formatting

I am trying to format the below code and it fails, the format function is not working as the braces are already in place.

```
def in_list(line):
  input = '{"word1":["one"], "word_list":{}, "bool":true}'.format(line)
  print(input)

msg = ["hello", "how", "are", "you"]
in_list(msg)



Expected Output:

'{"word1":["one"], "word_list":["hello","how","are","you"], "bool":true}'
```

Is there a way to pass the list into the sentence. Please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to double the brackets `{{`, `}}`

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
>   {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
>   text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include
>   a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling:
>   {{ and }}.

you can use:

```
def in_list(line):
    my_input = '{{"word1":["one"], "word_list":{0}, "bool":true}}'.format(line)
    print(my_input)

msg = ["hello","how","are","you"]
in_list(msg)

# {"word1":["one"], "word_list":['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], "bool":true}
```